# MvxAdapter binding items

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a MvxAdapter to show some images. The user can tap multiple images and the images get a selected-state.

At this moment I call following code everytime the user taps an image in the list:

```
_adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

This forces my MvxAdapter to reload the visible elements. My Adapter:

```
protected override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, int templateId)
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(templateId, parent, false);
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.Tag;

    if (holder == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder
        {
            Image = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.phonepictures_item),
            Foreground = convertView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.phonepictures_foreground)
        };

        convertView.Tag = holder;
    }
    // Code to load bitmap and selected state
    // ...

    // Set bitmap
    holder.Image.SetImageBitmap(bmp);

    // Set selected-layout <<<-----
    holder.Foreground.Visibility = (isSelected) ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;

    return convertView;
}
```

Everything works fine but I wonder if there is a solution with binding. Can I bind the visibility state of the Foreground-Element to my selected state of my image-model? I didn't find some examples on the web...

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the visibility with a value converter: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#the-mvx-visibility-valueconverters

In addition you can bind the image too:

```
public object Image
        {
            get
            {
                return //Load your image here as a byte[];
            }
        }
```

Then you can create a value converter like this:

```
public class ByteToBitmapValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<byte[], Bitmap>
    {
        protected override Bitmap Convert(byte[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(value, 0, value.Length);
        }
    }
```

Which can be bind to the view:

```
local:MvxBind="Bitmap ByteToBitmap(Image)"
```

I would say that you wouldn't need the custom list adapter at all if you fix the bindings.